# How to isolate php queries in single divs

Tags: php, html, css

I tried finding my question on the web but it looks like I am unable to formulate the question correctly. So, here it is : I want to display php queries in individual divs to do a grid view, just like e-commerce. Maybe there's another way around to post the results, if so, I would love your feedback! Thank you very much for your time!

HTML & PHP :

```
<div class="foo">
<?php    
//Execute the SQL code and return records
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $input1 = $row['input1'];    
        echo "<h2>$input1</h2>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.foo {
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is already putting all the results of $query into <div class="foo">. So, you really want that? Or you want to put every record of your query into their own <div> tags?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You're not displaying queries, you're displaying the results of the query. What parts of it do you want in individual DIVs? Could you show an example of what you want the resulting HTML to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$id = $row['ID'];
$input1 = $row['input1'];
echo '<div class="foo">'; 
echo "<h2>$input1</h2>";
echo "<hr>";
}
} else {
echo "No results found.";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, helped me a lot, since I didn't know how to put a div in php. The only thing I needed to change in order to make it work was to put the div closure inside the if loop, before the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening and closing the "individual" divs when you open and close the while loop respectively.

Comment: PS. `mysql_` functions ar **deprecated**..